# What is the reason for the /canvaskit/ folder in flutter wen builds

Tags: flutter-web

Hi there :) I recently noticed that a new /canvaskit/ folder was added to web projects in Flutter. [See here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yO4OK.png). The folder is included no matter what web renderer is chosen when running 'flutter build web'. The folder is very large, 16-ish MB. Does anyone know why this folder is suddenly present in builds?

Answer (score 5):

We have a couple of items to finish before this is complete (bundling fallback fonts, tooling, documentation), but this is the first step towards fully self-contained apps and out-of-the-box offline PWA support (https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/60069). We currently use it when running tests (it's faster and more stable when loaded from a local file vs from the network). You can use it today by adding the following to your `index.html` before loading `main.dart.js`:

```dart
<script>
  window.flutterConfiguration = {
    canvasKitBaseUrl: "/canvaskit/"
  };
</script>
```

Comment: why it is not automatically added when releasing web app? I've released my app and added this to index file then it worked.

Comment: What's the updated answer? This answer seems to be deprecated.